# RXTX how to send commands to device

Tags: java, rxtx

How to send by RXTX commends to device 
i found [this](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port) but how to send commands ?? Should it be string or hex or byte ?? I dont know

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the device you are talking to - if it's e.g. a [Hayes-compatible modem in command mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command_set), it dialogs in newline-separated strings, if your device talks some industrial protocol like [Modbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) you will be sending telegrams of bytes.

Anyways - serial communication on the PC is almost always asynchronous, and byte oriented.  This means that at the lowest level data are always sent as arrays of bytes, but depending on your application the higher level will be a string, or a raw array of bytes.

If you need to send bytes (I'm assuming that by HEX you mean raw bytes):  as you can see in the example code rxtx makes an[OutputStream](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%29) available, and that OutputStream has a .write(byte[]) method.  You can use that method to send bytes to the device.  Also have a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java) for extra sample code.

Comment: Commends to my device are in HEX, could U show me by example how to send it ??

Comment: This is my code http://pastebin.com/R4waQLMD but nothing happend i recive `start
/dev/ttyUSB0 -> null -> ` How to check if the commend was send correct ??

Comment: The most common way to debug a serial communication is by using a port monitor.  We use http://www.hhdsoftware.com/serial-monitor and we're pretty happy with it.  Mind you, if you want to debug a program that's not running on your development PC, or the communication between two devices, you'll need to use what they call bridge mode, a feature that's only available in the more expensive versions.